# How to update column value in Postgres table from Python based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, amazon-aurora

I have postgres table `(Alpha)` with following values

**Alpha**

```
ID  Exp_Date     Active_Status
1   7-12-2021    active
2   8-12-2021    active
3   15-12-2021   active
4   15-12-2021   active
5   11-12-2021   expired
6   1-12-2021    expired
7   6-12-2021    expired
```

**My Connection String**

```
postgres_str = f'postgresql://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}'
# Create the connection and cursor
rds_conn = psycopg2.connect(postgres_str)
rds_cur = rds_conn.cursor()
```

I want to update the `Active_Status` to expired based on two conditions

1. if `Exp_date` is less than `system date ( todays date)`
2. if `Active_Status ='active'`

**Expected Output**

```
ID  Exp_Date     Active_Status
1   7-12-2021    expired
2   8-12-2021    expired
3   15-12-2021   active
4   15-12-2021   active
5   11-12-2021   expired
6   1-12-2021    expired
7   6-12-2021    expired
```

How could the update query written from python for postgres

Comment: Do you want the SQL or the python aspect. cursor.execute.

Comment: @VynlJunkie,cursor execute

Answer (score 2):

1. I would learn to stay away from `f` strings when working with databases. I would suggest [make_dsn](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html?highlight=make_dsn#psycopg2.extensions.make_dsn)
2. It is just a SQL query, Python does not really enter in to it. Test in psql:

```
BEGIN;  
update 
   "Alpha" 
set 
   "Active_Status" = 'expired' 
where 
   "Exp_date" < current_date 
and 
   "Active_Status" = 'active';
--Then either COMMIT; or ROLLBACK; depending on whether it worked or not.
```

Then you can transfer the query to your psycopg2 code:

```
rds_cur.execute(<above_query>)
```